# twilio receive sms POST hook, get sms information

Tags: node.js, twilio-api

- So I have an account on Twilio, with the main phone number and an extra phone number (both US).
- I have a form on my application that posts to my server (nodejs - express), and from there, I send an SMS from the main # to the bought #.
- on the bought # i have a webhook (POST) pointing to another endpoint on my server
- I successfully send a message from web app -> my server -> bought #
- the web hook is hit, but there is no information on the POST body
- I am using bodyParser.json() and bodyParser.urlEncoded()

Am i doing something wrong?
how can i get the SMS information (origin #, dates, message...)

Comment: `console.log(request.body);`

Comment: nothing there, that's the first place i checked

Comment: Is your `bought #` at Twilio configured to make a `POST` to your end point, if yes, could you add to your question the relevant portion of the code so we can help you more?

Comment: I just found the solution, i was using bodyParser.urlencoded with extended: false, needs to be true. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

well, I was using `bodyParser({ extended: false })`, it needs to be true, so now i get the contents on req.body.